# Calling a method from all controllers

Tags: c#

This method checks the `Status` and based on that returns a `200` or `400` status code.

```
private IActionResult ResponseType(Response response)
    {
        if (response.Status)
            return Ok(response);
        return BadRequest(response);
    }
```

I want to call this method from all controllers, so I can determine if I should return a `200` or `400`. Where should I declare this method? In a "common" controller, service etc? What is the best practice for this use case?

Comment: class Static UtlHelper?

Comment: Wherever you like. I'd put it in an abstract base controller.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create `BaseController` which inherits from `System.Web.Mvc.Controller` in your project and write all common properties, methods and common logic here.

In any other controller inherit from this `BaseController`

**BaseController**

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
  public IActionResult ResponseType(Response response)
  {
    if (response.Status)
        return Ok(response);

    return BadRequest(response);
  }

  //Any other common methods, logics here
}
```

**All Other Controller**

```
public class AnyController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult GetResponseType(Response response)
    {
        return ResponseType(response);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could make the `BaseController` abstract.